# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure why I'm getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input error on this, to be honest I have used this snippet in many places before and never had this issue? I obviously am just code blind this afternoon!

```
<!-- jquery and bootstrap -->
<script src="js/libs.min.js?t=1494075642"></script>
<script src="js/template.js?t=1494075642"></script>
<script>
    // =======================
    // SUBMIT TO MAILCHIMP
    // =======================
    $(document).ready( function () {
    var action = "https://<<client_name>>.us13.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=207e8e8eebc7ed702d92e7928";
    var form = $('.mailchimp');

    if ( form.length > 0 ) {
        $('.mailchimp button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            form = $(this).closest(".mailchimp");
            register(form);
        });
    }

    function register(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            cache       : false,
            dataType    : 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error       : function(err) {
                alert("Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later.");
            },
            success     : function(data) {
                if (data.result != "success") {
                    $('#success').addClass("alert-danger").toggle().find("p").text(data.msg);
                    $('#mailchimpModal').modal('show');
                    $form.reset();
                } else {
                    $('#success').addClass("alert-success").toggle().find("p").text(data.msg);
                    $('#mailchimpModal').modal('show');
                    $form.reset();
                }
            }
        })
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Proper indentation will help to find the error

Answer (score 2):

You are missing ' }); ' at the bottom. Just add it right above the /script tag. You need to close out your $(document).ready( function() {